# How would one write a regex command to convert string to datetime format in python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-cleaning

How would one write the regex command to convert "yyyy-mm-ddXhh:mmY[GMT]" to a valid datetime format in python?

I am new to regex and tried the following, but it didnt work

```
df[df.columns['a']] = df[df.columns['a']].str.replace(r'[^0-9]+-[^0-9]+-[^0-9]+[A-Z][^0-9]+:[^0-9]+[A-Z][][A-Z]+[]', "")
```

Comment: you probably need `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: have you tried `pd.to_datetime()`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

str = "2019-06-09X14:38Y[GMT]"
y = re.split("Y", str)
x = re.split("X", y[0])

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(x[0]+' '+x[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
print(datetime_object)
```